# DynamoDB - Multiple range keys

Tags: database, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, serverless

Can we have more than 2 fields as primary key in DynamoDB.

Or can i create local secondary index for each field that i want to be a range key and build a query with multiple range keys simultaneously?

Comment: The simple answer to your first question is no, but that answer can be found easily in the documentation. A more specific question, which some background of what you are hoping to accomplish would make it a lot easier to answer your question.

Comment: I have three fields - A(ID) , B(TimeStamp), C(Type- Read, Unread) : Primary Key is A(partition key)with Sort Key B I am querying data with key condition expression - A & B and FilterExpression - C and using ScanIndexForward, and able to sort data on field B but it is scanning all the records for that ID even after applying filter on C="Unread". Then created Secondary Index A(partition key) with Sort Key C and using Secondary Index with KeyConditionExpression A & C, query is scanning only records where C="Unread" but now i am not able to Sort on field B, which is TimeStamp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the specifics you stated I believe what you need is a GSI with a composite index. Your table would look something like this:

```
Partition Key        GSI Partition          GSI Sort
ID                   ID                     Type+Timestamp
```

With this you can query the GSI with a filter expression like this:

```
#pk = :pk AND begins_with(#sk, :type)
```

Your `ExpressionAttributeNames` would need to map `#pk` to the ID field, and `#sk` to the name of the composite field.

Your `ExpressionAttributeValues` would need to map `:type` to the value you're searching for ("Read" or "Unread").

Because you are filtering on the type (the first part of the sort key) the first part of the sort key will always be the same, so the timestamp will be used for the ordering of the results.

Comment: for this - I have to insert data with one additional attribute : Type+Timestamp, right?

Comment: Thanks you Jason

Answer (score 2):

You can only have 2 fields as a primary key in DynamoDB. If you want multiple different range keys you can make a local secondary index for each one but you can still only query 1 index at a time. You can also only put 5 LSIs on a table.

What is the data you are trying to model? What are the query patterns that you need to support?

Comment: I have three fields - A(ID) , B(TimeStamp), C(Type- Read, Unread) :
         Primary Key is A(partition key)with Sort Key B 

I am querying data with key condition expression - A & B and FilterExpression - C and using ScanIndexForward, and able to sort data on field B but it is scanning all the records for that ID even after applying  filter on C="Unread".

Then created Secondary Index A(partition key) with Sort Key C and using Secondary Index  with KeyConditionExpression A & C, query is scanning only records where C="Unread" but now i am not able to Sort on field B, which is TimeStamp.

Comment: A filter expression is applied only after the scan/query is done. For example querying for A & B can return 1000 items, then filter for C will limit those 1000 down to 10.